# Finding the index of a vector from another vector

Tags: r

I have three vectors `a, r and b`. I want to check the first element of r is between zero and first element of vector `a` , if yes then put zero from vector `b`, if not , its belong to what interval and then extract the value form vector `b`, ...How can I do this in R?at the end I should have a vector with sample 20 and the values belong to vector `b`.

```
      a =c(0.1531532, 0.2432432, 0.3243243, 0.3648649, 0.3873874, 0.4054054, 
       0.4594595, 0.5720721, 0.7522523, 1.0000000)
      set.seed(2)
      r = runif(20, 0, 1)
      b = 0:9
      result = c( 1, 8, 8, 1, 9, 9, 0, 9, 7, 7, 7, 1, 9, 1, 5, 9, 9, 1, 6, 0)
```

Comment: Are you trying to do a weighted random sample from `b`? It's a bit hard to understand your question, but if that's what you want, there might be more direct ways to get there.

Comment: 1- You should set the seed to make your example reproducible. 2- You should add the expected output. 3- You should also show what you have tried. 4 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
R> a = c(0, a)
R> cut(r, a, labels = b)
 [1] 1 8 8 1 9 9 0 9 7 7 7 1 9 1 5 9 9 1 6 0
Levels: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Something like that looks like the go. You could simplify like `b[cut(r,c(0,a))]`

Comment: Is there any other way without using cut ?

Comment: @rose What's the problem with using `cut`? It seems to do exactly what you want

Comment: @rose - I dunno, I guess `findInterval` might also work. Those are your best options really as they are made for the task.